# How do I save a https certificate and put it in a pem-file on openssl?

Tags: openssl, certificate

With this command using **openssl** I managed to show the certificate of a website:

```
s_client -connect www.example.com:443 -showcerts
```

My task is to save the certificate in a **PEM**-file. How can  I do that ?

My next question: How do I create a text in **openssl**? I need to encrypt a message, then decrypt it. I couldn't do it and I spend a whole day to find a solution

It's my first time using **openssl** so I don't know much about it.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

## Question 1

You want to write X509-certifcates of `stackoverflow.com` into files 
and then show the information of certifcates using openssl. Here is how you can do this:

Redirect output of openssl into file `stackoverflow.txt`.

```
openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 -showcerts > stackoverflow.txt
```

The newly generated **stackoverflow.txt** contains the output of **s_client** including 
the certificates of *stackexchange.com* and *Let's Encrypt Authority X3*. The certificates are in format *BASE64 encoded X509*.

This is what you need to do get the certificates into separate files.
Open `stackoverflow.txt` with a texteditor and locate the lines beginning with `-----`
and copy the certifcate information including lines `-----` into two separate files `stackexchange_com.pem` and `lets_encrypt.pem`

> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIIHJjCCBg6gAwIBAgISA69Gnmaniop4xXZfJ5UjUouRMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
>   MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
>
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----

To show information about certificates:

```
openssl x509 -in stackexchange_com.pem -inform PEM -text
openssl x509 -in lets_encrypt.pem -inform PEM -text
```

## Question 2

You want to encyrpt and decrypt a textfile. Here is how you can do this:

Let file `file1.txt` contain the text you want to encrypt using *DES3*.
Then this allows you to encrypt the file and write the encrypted text into file `file1.des3`.

```
openssl des3 -salt -in file1.txt -out file1.des3 -pass pass:Dafs+@ww2-
```

Now `file1.des3` contains the encrypted information. To decrypt do this:

```
openssl des3 -d -salt -in file1.des3 -out file2.txt -pass pass:Dafs+@ww2-
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer! You saved my life, literally! You mentioned that I need to copy the certificates into different files but how exactly do I copy it?

Comment: s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 -showcerts > stackoverflow.txt   This one doesnt work on openssl, there is shown: "s_client: Use -help for summary."

Comment: For `>` to work the full command  has to be executed in the shell. (e.g bash shell or cmd.exe on windows) Therefore please execute this directly in the bash shell (or cmd,exe): `openssl s_client -connect stackoverflow.com:443 -showcerts > stackoverflow.txt`. 
Don't press CR after entering `openssl`, because then you are in `OpenSSL>` and `>` does not work.

Comment: okay this worked out (I guess), so I need to stay there and add before any command "openssl"?

Comment: And also I managed to open the text in my texteditor but what am I supposed to do next? What do you exactly mean with copy?

Comment: With copy I mean copy the text into clipboard. Then open another editor paste the text there and save it to a file. Copy=`Copy/Paste To/From clipboard`